# The Robolectric-Tests case errors with Room-library(arch-component)

Tags: android, robolectric, android-room, android-architecture-components, robolectric-gradle-plugin

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Error(s) present: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal connection pointer 1. Current pointers for thread Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-8,5,main] []] (latch = 0, values = 0, errors = 1, completions = 0)
```

I use Room to play with SQLite. Everything is fine when the application runs and single-test will be played. All successfully.

The problem is if I run  Robolectric-tests with more than two cases, the tests can not run go through. 
Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742685/robolectric-running-multiple-tests-fails) , [this](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwimwtK2qqfXAhWQpqQKHVF3CA0QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frobolectric%2Frobolectric%2Fissues%2F1890&usg=AOvVaw3LRUXbUBoVXbXfs60iEy8M) . They help might be at other ORMs, howerver, doesn't help at Room.

Any idea? Also asked [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3507) .

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same issue

you need to close database

```
 @After
 public void closeDb() throws IOException {
    database.close();
 }
```

And also, I noticed, that if one test (*which works with database*) fails, than every tests would fail too with such error. So, make sure that every tests works fine by standalone.